# MSVS 12, C++, command arguments not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, command-line-arguments

I'm using C++ in Microsoft Visual Studio 12.  I want to pass command line arguments.  I have tried listing them in the MSVS's Project/Properties/Debugging/Command Arguments field and I've also tried using the CLIArgsMadeEasy add on but it never works. argc is always 1 where, of course, argv[0] is the app path.
Example: given a program of fred.exe that I would like to launch with three args : a,b,c
i.e. the equivalent of a cmd window line of

**fred.exe a b c**

I specify the args in the provided edit boxes exactly as:

**a b c**

using either method described above (MSVS standard or CLIArgsMadeEasy) but when I run they aren't passed.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <iomanip>  // for controlling float print precision
#include <sstream>  // string to number conversion
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
```

...

Comment: Are you running your program in debug mode from VS?

Comment: project properties → debugging → command arguments

Comment: 1) Yes, I am running the from debug mode in VS.  I was building and running a release as that didn't work I changed to debug.  X64. 2) As per my post, I did try project properties → debugging → command arguments (and after that didn't work I installed the CLIArgsMadeEasy add on but that didn't help either)

Comment: For others having similar issue, on my VS 2015 it is possible (feature?) that Project Properties opens on last <Platform,Configuration> you had opened recently. As dumb as it sounds it may happen (guilty here) that people assume project Property will open current build/debug configuration, and they end up modifying command line args _not_ for the binary they are debugging.
TL;DR: check whether edition is on cmd args for the same <Configuration,Platform> as the build/debug one

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this program in my visual studio and it works:

```html
#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <iomanip>  // for controlling float print precision
#include <sstream>  // string to number conversion
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
 {
  cout << i << ":" << argv[i] << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

[image]